# Is this technique image processing or computer vision?

Tags: image-recognition, computer-vision, machine-translation, image-processing

If I use my mobile camera on a signboard or announcement board on a road or in a street (like the one attached in photo) where the message is written in Russian and my mobile shows me that message in English, would this be an image processing or computer vision technique?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a computer vision task, given that it requires a high-level understanding of the image (that is, it contains text, and the text needs to be translated to another language), which can use an image processing technique (for example, to deblur the possibly blurry original photo).